# GUI for Tmux and Vim?

Tags: user-interface, vim, tmux

Just wondering, is there a general GUI available?

Like MacVim is to Vim for the Mac, is there a GUI Terminal where everything looks nice on it, especially Tmux?

I'm wondering if there's a GUI that supports both Vim and Tmux at the same time.

Comment: I use vim on tmux most of the time, simply opening a shell; what do you mean about an extra gui? doesn't the terminal menu bar suffices it? all you need is on the inside (tmux + vim) (: If you're looking for a gui for a terminal multiplexer, you may be nicely served with terminator, or xterm -- never used none of them, but heard from friends these apps work very well

Comment: I see I will check these out. I mean like, you know how you can use MacVim or `vim` in the Terminal? That's what I mean. A Terminal dedicated to these programs, making them shine in their graphics. Like giving them full color support or better cursor etc. That kind of GUI, toolbars suck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside support for thousands of colors, GUI Vim doesn't offer anything useful that's not in CLI Vim: windows separators, signs, folds, etc. are still drawn with characters, you don't even have rounded corners… well, tabs, OK. It's even less useful in some ways because it doesn't have a proper terminal emulator built-in, for example!

If you want "physical" pane separators and tabs with bevels and all, Terminator or iTerm provide those. iTerm even offers some level of tmux integration.

Comment: OK, that helps. I might check out Terminator although I'm already using iTerm. I don't want anything the GUI provides except a better look for the Terminal itself. I wouldn't be using Tmux if I used GUI tabs. What I mean is the excellent support MacVim gives for Vim, but for Tmux and other applications as well. A better looking Terminal you might say, but what it outputs not the applications look. I hope that's clearer. :)

Comment: No that's not clearer. How would a red rectangle with a `t` in it look better than another red rectangle with a `t` in it? What do you call "excellent support MacVim gives for vim"? The only difference on my Mac or here on this ubuntu box between GUI Vim and CLI Vim is the number of colors available for my colorscheme. Besides that, the experience is exactly the same.

Comment: Well, besides the color support, the cursor support (like in my other question, which you probably already solved), and, is that really all that it improves? I believe the font smoothing was better or something like that (although it doesn't matter).

Comment: The font smoothing is delegated to OS-wide subsystems in your terminal and in MacVim. I don't see any added value at all. I simply tend to use GUI Vim when I'm already in GUI land and CLI Vim when I'm in CLI land: I have the exact same settings/mappings/plugins for both and use both in exactly the same way.

Comment: I see, yes you are right. I think I'll study a bit changing the cursor with Terminal and through Tmux and see how that goes. I might just make a plugin out of it. lol. Thanks for your time, I will accept your answer in order to close this question.

Comment: By the way, xterm and konsole support 24-bit color (`\e[38;2;{R};{G};{B}m` for foreground, `48` in place of `38` for background, all colors are decimal numbers from `0` to `255`). Likely other terminal emulators if they aim to be xterm-compatible. I will probably write a patch for vim to support this as well if I have time before I forget about the idea.

Comment: If somebody is interested, current work on this issue is [here](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/src/24-bit-xterm) (bookmark 24-bit-xterm). Latest (and the only) commit should work, but I have not really tested it. To enable use `set guicolors`. If it does not compile, try disabling gui.

Comment: One update: research revealed that the only terminal supporting 24-bit color is not xterm (it uses closes neighbor, not real 24-bit color), but konsole: exactly ***one*** terminal of 3 I am using and 13 having stable versions in Gentoo repository (only stable versions were checked). Xterm is exactly another ***one*** using closes color from 16-bit palette, others just don’t understand the sequence. I guess that if I succeed with the patch and it will be merged it would be a good point for starting to push feature requests to terminal emulator authors.

Comment: Posted to [vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/ed0GTyYrSYg). This will be last comment here.

Comment: That's not all together true in the MacVim case. The default version of vim that comes installed on the osx term doesn't have +python, +ruby and a whole list of other things. MacVim has all of these already compiled in for you and ready to go. There are also some other neat gui features available in Gvim that I do not think exist in the default term vim. The one that jumps to my mind first is being able to drag the window divider with the mouse. The best answer is that iterm 2 gives you the gui aspect and as you mentioned has some tmux integration.

Comment: No. Your MacVim vs default Vim comparison is off-topic because my answer was more general: GUI Vim vs CLI Vim. MacVim's CLI executable, for example, has everything MacVim has, but runs *in* your terminal emulator. And yes, using the mouse to drag window separators is perfectly possible in CLI Vim.

Comment: @ZyX i couldn't find you elsewhere, writing here. i got vim up and running in true colors (feels damn awesome). but thing i can't figure out is if this can be combined with tmux?

Comment: @ArnisL. You need to escape these sequences both in tmux and screen. The [example escape code is here](https://github.com/ZyX-I/powerline/blob/669327df0d25a896179da9a7c567f0c25c1186c6/powerline/renderers/shell.py#L58), but note that it is known not to actually work in tmux (produces strange gaps) when using powerline, but also known to work fine in screen. There currently is no way to make this escaping code into vim other then patching source or running vim in another terminal emulator which will proxy properly escapes to tmux (you will have to write this by yourself).

Comment: @ZyX thank you very much for taking time to write this. otherwise I couldn't really understand where I'm at.

Comment: @ZyX i hacked tmux so it would pass through 38;2 and 48;2 sequences https://gist.github.com/ArnisL/6156593